# How do I change my cron loglevel to 7 from default value 1?

Tags: 14.04, cron, log

`> man cron`, tells me that the default log level for cron is 1; i.e. cron "*will log the start of all cron jobs.*"
I want to set that to 7, so I checked in all the wrong places, starting with the file `/etc/syslog.d/50-default.conf`. I am running Trusty 14.04.
Pointers anyone ?

Comment: For 16.04 and systemd I could only get [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/740499/reduce-cron-log-level-with-systemd) method to work, even though `/etc/default/cron` says "This file has been deprecated".

Comment: btw, in 16.04 the 50-default.conf file is crucial if you want to break out system.log to also produce a separate cron.log, as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-its-own-log-file-so-it-can-be-monitored-in-real

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the cron init script (`/etc/init/cron.conf`) as follow:

```
# cron - regular background program processing daemon
#
# cron is a standard UNIX program that runs user-specified programs at
# periodic scheduled times

description "regular background program processing daemon"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect fork
respawn

exec cron -L 7
```

Comment: This is the old way that worked up until a FRESH install of 16.04 LTS.  Upgrades from 14.04 to 16.04 still work this way, however.  Same with using `service cron restart` - works fine until a 16.04 FRESH install.

Answer (score 0):

Or if your installation doesn't have the `/etc/init/cron.conf` file, then edit the `/etc/init.d/cron` file by adding:-

```
EXTRA_OPTS="-L 0"
```

in the parameters section.

Comment: Did you mean `EXTRA_OPTS="-L 7" ` ?