# 16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?

Tags: 16.04, cron, log, syslog

I know that cron events are stored in `/var/log/syslog` and I can use a command like:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron
```

to see them.

I'd much rather have the system keep a separate cron log file so it doesn't do as much work watching it, as it sorts through all the `syslog` messages to pull out the `cron` notifications.

Then I want to use the `watch` command so I always have an open terminal window showing cron activity.

How do I make the system keep a separate `/var/log/cron.log` file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Here is the simplest way to do it:**

-->  Make a change in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` with your favorite editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> (find) and type `cron` to find the line that says

```
#cron.*         /var/log/cron.log
```

Remove the `#` from that line. Then restart the service:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

**From then on, all cron-related output will go to `/var/log/cron.log`**

---

In order to prevent `cron` from sending summary emails, place this line at the beginning of your `crontab` file:

```
crontab -e
(Insert first line)
MAILTO=""
```

---

**Then to watch it in near-real-time, first create a `wcron` command:**

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" >wcron
echo "watch -n 10 tail -n 25 /var/log/cron.log" >>wcron
chmod +x wcron
sudo cp wcron /usr/sbin
```

- watch -n 10 tells it to refresh the page every 10 seconds
- tail -n 25 tells it to display the last 25 entries

---

**Whenever you want to monitor `cron` in near-real-time in a terminal window, enter:**

```
wcron
```

This is handy to have open in one of the 4 virtual desktops, perhaps along with System Monitor.

---

**If you want to see more than just the launch times of longer jobs, it is easy to make the cron.log show both script start times and script end times, along with non-zero exit status messages.**

[How to change cron log level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949996/how-to-change-cron-log-level/)

PARAPHRASED EXCERPT:

> From Ubuntu 15.04 on, **upstart** using `/etc/init/*.conf` is replaced
>   by **systemd** using configuration files in `/lib/systemd/system/` and
>   `/etc/systemd/system/`. Although a file `/etc/init/cron.conf` is still
>   existent in Ubuntu 16.04, the script normally in use to start `cron`
>   now is **`/lib/systemd/system/cron.service`**.

To add the `-L 15` option, open the editor by using:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full cron
```

OR I RECOMMEND:

```
sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system/cron.service
```

and replace the line

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS
```

with

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -L 15 -f $EXTRA_OPTS
```

Then reload the configuration:

```
sudo systemctl restart cron
```

It will load it on boot also.

---

**This enables `wcron` to show all the information you need to watch your cron system as it runs your scripts on schedule.**

---

**One final idea for monitoring `cron` is to teach your scripts to speak.**

[16.04 LTS How to make the system announce the time at the top of the hour with eSpeak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977613/16-04-lts-how-to-make-the-system-announce-the-time-at-the-top-of-the-hour-with-e)

I have many of my scripts announce when they start and when they stop, or if they encounter errors.

Volume may be adjusted in the `espeak` command so they can be subtle.

Comment: Depends on the audience, I suppose.  So I changed it to say this is the simplest way to do it.  ;-)  One thing I can say is that this is my default screen on my main servers:   `wcron` with System Monitor over the top of it.  Gives a great overview.  Plus, I use `espeak` so the `cron` jobs announce their progress or errors.

Comment: 1: On Debian systems like Ubuntu, the extra options to cron are defined in `/etc/default/cron`. That is where you should have `EXTRA_OPTS="-L 15"`
2: If you need to modify a systemd service file (which you don't in this case), changes go under `/etc/systemd/system/...`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/8822) or [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Modify).