# Opening vim inside terminator window

Tags: command-line, vim, terminator

[image]I have started using the terminator emulator, and overall it's great. One annoying issue I have however, is that everytime I open up vim inside of it the window acts very odd. Basically all the symbols get wacky and it's illegible. Even doing screen redraw doesn't help.

However, if I open one addition terminal window , the original window with Vim inside goes back to normal. 
I'd like to not always open a new window for Vim to work, so i'm hoping someone has perhaps had a similar issue.

I think be a vimrc setting that's off. I could put part of it up if that would help. Thanks

Here's some of the vimrc file:

```
"source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
"source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
"behave mswin

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>


"set t_Co=256
" Let's set the wrap margin

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
" runtime! debian.vim

filetype plugin on
set hlsearch

"set foldmethod=syntax
"set foldnestmax=1


"set shellcmdflag=-ic


autocmd  BufRead,BufNewFile /tmp/calcurse* set filetype=tex
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile ~/.calcurse/notes/* set filetype=tex

"if has('gui_running')
"  set guifont=Lucida_Console:h11
"endif

"set termguicolors


set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
"set t_ut=

"set background=light ## Heading ##
"syntax enable 
"let g:solarized_termcolors=16

"colo desert

" Setting up the relative numbering feature.
set relativenumber 

set foldlevelstart=99

set nocompatible

set shellslash

"innoremap <expr><buffer><silent> gb  ':!zathura --synctex-forward 
'.line(".").':'.col('.').':% ' . 
shellescape(g:latex#data[b:latex.id].out()) . ' >/dev/null<CR>'
let g:livepreview_previewer = 'zathura'
nmap <F12> :LLPStartPreview<cr>

set sw=8

let mapleader=','
"filtetype indent on


set ttimeout



let g:tex_flavor ='pdflatex'

let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat ='pdf'

let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -
interaction=nonstopmode $*'

let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'zathura'



"let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex --interaction=nonstopmode $*'
"let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex -interaction=nonstopmode  $*'
```

Comment: Need more information.  Which version are you suing?  Are you at the console, or is this over a ssh connection?

Comment: I'm not sure what version.  I think I am at the console but I don't know much about linux still. I use I3window manager over ubuntu and I used to use the standard terminal emulator that comes with ubuntu. Then I installed terminator using the command line. So now when I do the keypress in i3 to bring up a terminal terminator comes up.

Comment: It's really hard to imagine what "acts very odd", "all the symbols", "get wacky" etc. mean. Could you post a screenshot or screencast?

Comment: If you think there's something wrong with your `vimrc` file, do you mind attaching its content to your question?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to take a screenshot inside of the i3 window manager and couldn't figure out how. I then tried to take a screenshot from within Ubuntu but there the issue (as I just saw) does not come up. @egmont by get wacky I mean that: as I scroll down or start typing much of the text disappears (these are non empty tex files)  and only randomw characters are left on the screen. When I hit <C-L> the screen redraws but when I start typing again the same issue occurs. As I said the fix so far is to open a new terminal and immediately close to.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I'll try and figure out how to screenshot from in i3, if that doesn't work i'll look up what a screencast is.

Comment: @Jmaff maybe you can manually run the `gnome-screenshot` or `shutter` commands

Comment: FAQs give some troubleshooting tips which may be useful: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5

Comment: screencast == video. Worst case take a photo (or video) with a camera (e.g. mobile phone).

Comment: I downloaded the screencast package. I'm just trying to upload the video now. All I am doing in the short video is a bunch of scrolling and or vim keystrokes that involve movement like: gg , <Shift-G> kk etc. Thank you.

Comment: ** I added my `.vimrc` in the answer below - it is very simple.  Optimized for editing Python and works fine for `bash`

Answer (score -2):

**Thank you for posting this question!   I am using this every day now.**

---

You can find out the version of Ubuntu you are using with this command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

---

Under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS `terminator` installs like so:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

and run by typing:

```
terminator
```

`vim` can be installed from inside the `terminator` window

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

and run it by typing

```
vim
```

- It works just fine.  Nothing strange about it at all.

---

You can open a window to the right with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

And another just below it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

- `vim` works fine in all of them.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes the "current window" which you can select with your mouse.

---

**Also, if you right-click inside a window it gives the options to split it horizontally or vertically or close it.**

---

Here is an example of using `vim` in the top screen.

**`/home/pi/.vimrc` looks like this:**

```
syntax enable
set number
set ts=4
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set cursorline
set showmatch
let python_highlight_all = 1
```

[image]

---

Regurlarly I monitor my `cron` activity by opening one window below

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)

```
wcron
```

to get my real-time `cron` log monitor running, as per:

[16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time)

---

Then in this example I have `wcron` in the bottom part, and above it I ran a script that went out to the OUTSIDE data-logger to run an `rsync` back to the hard drive of the mothership.

[image]

---

This is great.  Makes the Ubuntu experience much more rich on a single monitor.