# Where can I find the output log from a custom crontab task

Tags: cron

I configured a regular task

```
me@alpha:~$ crontab -l | grep '^\*'
*/5 * * * * (cd ~/Documents/OrgMode; git add .; git commit -m "defensively save")
```

It works but I cannot find the log in `mail.log`

```
me@alpha:~$ grep 'git' /var/log/mail.log
me@alpha:~$ grep 'git' /var/log/mail.log
```

Where could I find the log?

Comment: sorry? it works? Doubt it. cron does NOT work with shell expansion so the "~" will not change to /home/$USER/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For see  log entry about cron service excute this command on ubuntu 18.04+:

```
journalctl -u cron.service
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 see this questions: [16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time/966195#966195)